# I want to understand why this particular tensor flow warning is coming up...?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I think so that this could be affected both due to some intricacies in tensorflow-gpu package and tensorflow package package that's why I am getting this...

I am just trying to train a normal softmax classifier with two hidden layers and inputting the required tensor in tf.float32 format but I am getting this error...

```
WARNING: Entity <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4EC7C8AC8>> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutgoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4EC7C8AC8>>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
WARNING: Entity <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4ECE5AE48>> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutgoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4ECE5AE48>>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
WARNING: Entity <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4ECE5AE48>> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutgoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <bound method Dense.call of <tensorflow.python.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002F4ECE5AE48>>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
```

I don't understand what does this mean and even I have also tried to ignore warnings but still I am getting this and all I want to understand is how is this warning coming up..?

The code snippet is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
n_features = X_train_centered.shape[1]
n_classes = 10
random_seed = 123
np.random.seed(random_seed)

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(random_seed)
    tf_x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32,shape = (None,n_features),name = 'tf_x')
    tf_y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32,shape = None,name = 'tf_y')
    y_onehot = tf.one_hot(indices = tf_y,depth = n_classes)
    h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = tf_x,units = 50,activation = tf.tanh,name = 'layer1')
    h2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = h1,units = 50,activation = tf.tanh,name = 'layer2')
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs = h2,units = 10,activation = None,name = 'layer3')
    predictions = {'classes': tf.argmax(logits,axis = 1,name = 'predicted_classes'),'probabilities' : tf.nn.softmax(logits,name = 'softmax_tensor')}
```

- I also tried downgrading gast to a different version, but that still doesn't work
- Here, `X_centered` is just the inputted data...
- I commented and checked that the warning start to occur when I uncomment the first `tf.layer.dense` allocation to `h1`...

Comment: For starters, it would be helpful to know the specific line of code causing this error. gast isn't explicitly mentioned in your code, so it's being called somewhere within one of the other packages you're calling yourself. Identifying this location would be a good first step to debugging your code

Comment: I don't know if it still an actual problem, but I had the same problem because I use the shape attribute of a tensor. However, it seems that it is not the case for you, but you can look at visit_Subscript from tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\qual_names.py file.                                              
 By the way you can activate the verbose 10 with 
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(10, alsologtostdout=True) to have the full stack

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with gast, a tf dependency.
Downgrading to gast 0.2.2 has solved it for most developers.
So run: pip install gast==0.2.2 and it should be solved.

(For reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32859)